# Changing speed of a part of a video

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to slow down only a small part of my video. I used this filter_complex:

```
[0:v]     split=3                                     [p1][p2][p3];
[p1]      trim=start=1.19:end=34.19                   [x];         
[p2]      trim=34.19:36.39,setpts=2*N/FRAME_RATE/TB   [y];         
[p3]      trim=start=36.39                            [z];         
[x][y][z] concat=3                                    [video]
```

In the resulting `[video]` the `[x]` and `[y]` are OK, but after it the last frame of `[y]` is frozen for many seconds (about 36), showing it as a *still frame*, and only after it is playing the `[z]` part.

I think that something is wrong with the presentation time stamp of the `[z]` part, but I have no idea how to fix it. Or - maybe - reach my goal by other, simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trim filter does not reset timestamps, but the concat filter expects each segment to start with 0 timestamp. So,

```
[0:v]     split=3                                         [p1][p2][p3];
[p1]      trim=start=1.19:end=34.19,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS   [x];         
[p2]      trim=34.19:36.39,setpts=2*N/FRAME_RATE/TB       [y];         
[p3]      trim=start=36.39,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS            [z];         
[x][y][z] concat=3                                        [video]
```